# Parametrization of the line in the projective space

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Let $L=aX+bY+cZ$ be a line in the projective space, the book I'm using states that every such line has the following parametrization:

$$\varphi:\mathbb P^1\to L, \ (t:s)\mapsto (\alpha_1t+\beta_1s:\alpha_2t+\beta_2s: \alpha_3t+\beta_3s)$$

To prove that I'm trying first to understand why this is a parametrization of the line, if anyone could help me I would be really grateful.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First notice that the image of $\varphi$ is indeed a projective line.

It is clear that $\alpha=[\alpha_1:\alpha2:\alpha3]$ and $\beta=[\beta_1:\beta_2:\beta_3]$ are in this image (they are respectively $\varphi(1:0)$ and $\varphi(0:1)$).

Now, as 3D-vectors, the elements of the image of $\varphi$ are the vectors coplanar to $\alpha$ and $\beta$ (since they are the linear combinations of the two), so in $\mathbb P^2$, they form a projective line.

Conversely, take any line $L\subset \mathbb P^2$, it is completely determined by a pair of points $\alpha,\beta\in L$, which can define the parametrization $\varphi:\mathbb P^1\to L$ as above.

Comment: To prove $Im \ (\varphi) \subset L$, I would argue this is true simply because the codomain of $\varphi$ is $L$, am I right?

Comment: This is not correct: The way $\varphi$ is defined only allows you to say that its codomain is $\mathbb P^2$. It is the fact that the elements in $\Im(\varphi)$ are on a line (using the argument I give above) that proves the inclusion.

Comment: But I defined $\varphi$ with a codomain $L$. Anyway, I have to use your argument to prove that $\varphi$ is well defined.

Comment: Either you decide $L$ is the codomain of $\varphi$ and you have to prove that its explicit description is consistent or you decide the codomain is $\mathbb P^2$ and you have to prove that the image is in $L$. It is just a matter of point of view.

Comment: yes, that was I've been thinking, you're right.

Comment: Dear zozoens, I didn't understand how a pair of points can define a parametrization $\varphi:\mathbb P^1\to L$ as above.

Comment: He means "if you pick any two distinct points for $\alpha$ and $\beta$, the construction above yields a map from $P^1$ to $P^2$ whose image is the line containing $\alpha$ and $\beta$, as the discussion above shows."

Comment: This is precisely what I meant.

Answer (score 0):

First consider the map $f:\mathbb{A}\to \mathbb{A}^3$ given by $$s\mapsto (x=\alpha_1 +\beta_1s,y=\alpha_2 +\beta_2s,z=\alpha_3 +\beta_3s),$$ with $<\beta_1,\beta_2,\beta_3>\neq<0,0,0>$. If you take any two pints in the image of this map and subtract their coordinates you will get a vector in the same direction as $<\beta_1,\beta_2,\beta_3>$. And since the image is one dimensional it must necessarily be a line. Homogenize everything to projective coordinates to obtain the analogous result in projective space. Now given an arbitrary line passing through points $P$ and $Q$ in $\mathbb{A}^3$, take $<\beta_1,\beta_2,\beta_3>$ to be say the vector emanating from $P$ and terminating at $Q$ and take $<\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3>$ to be the coordinates of $P$. Then the map $f$ will be a parmatrization of your line.